# The Method is not applicable for the arugment

Tags: java, abstract

I get the error mentioned in the title with the following very simple code, and I am not sure what the problem is, I know it is most likely a very simple fix but it has been so long since I done coding I can't bring anything to mind.

```
s1.setaddress("31 Main street");
```

that is the snippet that shows the error and the code that I think affects this is from the student class first then the second snippet will be master class person

```
@Override
public String getaddress() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return address;
}
@Override
public String setaddress() {
    return address;
}
```

person class

```
public abstract class Person {
protected String name;
protected String surname;
protected String address;
protected int age;

public abstract String getName();
public abstract String getsurName();
public abstract String getaddress();

public abstract String setName();
public abstract String setsurName();
public abstract String setaddress();
public abstract int age();

public String toString(){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "Name: " + name + " " + surname + "Age: " + age + "\n"  + "Address: " + address;
};
```

thanks for any help

Comment: is it during compile time or runtime, also `setAddress` does not have any iny parameter like `setAddress(String address)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setAddress` should accept an argument which modifies the `address` field:

```
@Override
public String setaddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
```

As this is an overridden method, you need to have the same signature in the base class too:

`public abstract String setaddress(String address);`

You can also get rid of the return type `String` in the above declarations as it has now become useless.

Comment: It should have the return type `void`, or return something.

Answer (score 2):

Your `setAddress` method does not accept any parameters but you are trying to call it with a `String`.

Try:

```
public void setAddress(String str) {
    this.address=str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `getaddress()` and `setaddress()` methods are the same, so I think it's just copy-paste typo. Valid `setaddress()` should be as the following:

```
@Override
public void setaddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
```

Don't forget to change return type at the abstract class also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tried this however I just get the error The method setaddress(String) of type Students must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: @TAM yep, as I said you should change return type of this method at the parent Person class. Change `String` to `void` there